# SQL records to JSON Single Object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database

I need to convert a 2 columns result to JSON using first as field and second as value.

Given the fallowing records

| FomrField | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | Jhon |
| Age | 51 |
| Job | Artist |

I would need the next JSON Result:

{
"Name": "Jhon",
"Age": "51",
"Job": "Artist"
}

I have tried "for json path":

`select FormField, Value from FormsData for json path -- for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`

But what I'm looking for is one single json object, and what I get with the previous approach is either an array or a bunch of objects, always having two sets of key-values based on the columns name.

Comment: SELECT  '{'+STRING_AGG('"'+FomrField+'":'+'"'+Value+'"',',')+'}'
FROM Table. Could you please try this?

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran, Get this:
STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: Could you try this FOR JSON AUTO, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

Comment: You can CAST the Column as NVARCHAR(MAX) to avoid the Limit error

Comment: @SrinivasanRajasekaran, it worked for the avobe usecase, but when things get complicated it fails, I have to run a couple more tests, anyway thanks very much.

Comment: @AkshayPhadke, I tried that, but is fetching the data in not a desired way

Comment: select * from Emp for JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER Try this 
Output ` {"Id":1,"name":"xyz"},{"Id":2,"name":"abc"} `

Comment: Have you tried to [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) `Value` for `FormField` before applying `FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`?

Comment: You can build your own: `SELECT '{' + (
select  '''' + FormField + ''': ''' + [Value] + ''',' 
from FormsData
for xml PATH ('')
) + '}'` but I think you should address another type of problems like the conversion; with this approach you have `{'Name': 'jhon','Age': '51','Job': 'Artist',
}` where Age is a string.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).